# Install SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows Server 2012 Essentials RC

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I can't Install SQL Server 2008 Express on Server 2012 Essentials

Commandline:

/q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS2008 /INSTANCEID=SQLExpress2008 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"

I get an exception:

Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578304
  Exit facility code:            1204
  Exit error code:               0
  Exit message:                  Network Service or Local Service account is not permitted for the SQL Server service on a domain contoller. Specify a different account.
  Start time:                    2012-09-17 15:55:44
  End time:                      2012-09-17 15:55:56
  Requested action:              Install

Which account should I use?

Comment: `Network Service or Local Service account is not permitted for the SQL Server service on a domain contoller. Specify a different account` It's a pity they don't provide clear error messages

Answer (score 0):

you should assign it an account from Active Directory.  We typically create DBSERVERNAME_SQL or something similiar for this service account. Because it sounds like you're on a domain controller, I don't think that you'll have a choice but to create an active directory account.